# "We have lot of money" or "We have a lot of money"

Tags: plural-forms, determiners

> 1) We have lot of money.
>
> 2) We have a  lot of money.

Which is correct?

I say "we have lot of money."

[Google](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20lot%20of%20money,have%20lot%20of%20money&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) says "we have a lot of money" is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"We have **a** lot of money" is correct. "a lot" is the correct phrase, not simply "lot". "lot" is a singular noun, so it usually requires a determiner - in this case "a".

However, and this is probably what is confusing here, there is also the word "lots". "We have lots of money" is also correct, as "a lot of" and "lots of" have the same meaning.

Therefore, these are also correct:

- "We have a lot of cars" and "We have lots of cars".
- "I know a lot of people" and "I know lots of people".

Comment: Okay, if it is so, why we say "after a lot of struggle" and not "after a lot of struggle". See the ngram result here http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=After+a+lot+of+struggle%2CAfter+lots+of+struggle%2CAfter+a+lot+of+struggles&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @user43286 Please clarify: Both of your quotes are the same. I *assume* you are asking about "a lot of stuggleS" - as all my examples were plural (or obviously uncountable). This is not exactly on-topic for this particular question, however, so I'm keeping this in the comments: "struggle" when used as a synonym of "effort" (rather than "fight" or similar) is more often than not [considered uncountable](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/effort). See the "a lot of effort" there.

Comment: yes that was a typo. why do we say "a lot of struggle" and not "a lot of struggles"? So you are saying "a lot of struggles" is wrong sentence and it should be "a lot of struggle"?

Comment: @user43286 It's "a lot of struggle" when it's about *effort* - you had to invest a lot of energy into it. It's "a lot of struggles" when you've had to punch beings (people, animals, dragons) to get there.

Comment: @user43286, FEichinger: The plural "a lot of struggles" simply implies that you had *several **different*** difficulties requiring effort to overcome (so you struggled more than once). The singular form is several times more common anyway, but it's worth pointing out that we often lump all of several difficulties together into one. It would be quite reasonable to say a soccer team, for example, had a lot of struggle, but won the league. They played & won many games through the season, but we can just treat them all as a "collective singular" obstacle that was overcome.

Comment: I propose following @FEichinger's example and redefining "struggle" to mean "punch a being (specifically a person, animal or dragon)." Letter writing campaign to Oxford, anyone?